# python how to make this distance formula code in a Surd form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formula, solver

I'm trying to solve a distance formula for a question, however, I want the answer as a surd form in 
    python. The code is below:

```
import math
#taking values of x and y
px1=int(input("What is value of px1?: "))
py1=int(input("What is value of py1?: "))
qx2=int(input("What is value of pqx2?: "))
qy2=int(input("What is value of qy2?: "))
#formula for the distance 
formula = ((qx2-px1)**2+(qy2-py1)**2)
i = int(math.sqrt(formula) )
print(i)
```

Comment: you mean as equation?

Comment: I mean give the answer as surd form in python

Comment: post some example of `surd form`, don't know what you mean by this.